# Pip installing module to different python installations on mac

Tags: python, macos, pip

On a fresh mac OS X(tried both Maverick and Yosemite), I am getting strange results from pythons pip.

I have installed a new version of python in /usr/local/bin/python, and the original version of python still lives at /usr/bin/python. My installation of python is set as the default.

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

When installing my python module, pip installs all the dependencies to `/usr/local/bin/python` which is correct. However, it adds the she-bang line of `/usr/bin/python` to the console scripts.

Now when I use my console script, I get an import error, because the dependencies don't exist in that version of python.

I can fix this by hand by editing the she-bang line

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

and all is fine.

So, here is my question. Why is this happening? Why is pip installing all the dependencies to one version, and using the she-bang from a different version?

More important question, how can I prevent this from happening, so anyone else who installs my module doesn't have to go change this line themselves?

---

Here is my setup.py:

```
import sys

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import foobar

requires = ['pyyaml==3.11',
            'six==1.8.0',
            'cement==2.4',
            'setuptools>=7.0',
            'python-dateutil>=2.2',
            ]

setup_options = dict(
    name='foobar',
    version=foobar.__version__,
    description='Command Line Interface.',
    long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
    author='Humdinger',
    url='example.com',
    packages=find_packages('.', exclude=['tests*', 'docs*']),
    package_dir={'foobar': 'foobar'},
    install_requires=requires,
    classifiers=(
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Intended Audience :: System Administrators',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    ),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo=foobar.foo:main'
        ]
    }
)

setup(**setup_options)
```

---

Upon suggestion, I have added the line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to my setup.py and foo.py file.

This does not seem to solve the problem.

---

I have also tried to re-try on a fresh mac OSX without installing my own version of python.

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

$ head -1 $(which pip)
#!/usr/bin/python

$ head -1 $(which eb)
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: What does the shebang of your console script(s) look like before installing with pip?

Comment: Console script doesnt exist before I install it with pip

Comment: I meant in your source

Comment: As I said, the she-bang points to: `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @ErlVolton or are you asking for something else?

Comment: I'm trying to verify that in your console scripts source code you're meeting the requirements listed here to have your shebang line automatically set to the correct interpreter:  https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts

Comment: @ErlVolton Added my setup.py

Comment: Can we see the exact shebang line that's in one of the console scripts, as it stands in the source before you install the package?

Comment: @ErlVolton There is none. None of my python or source files have any she-bang lines

Comment: Did you try `#!/usr/bin/env python`?

Comment: @m.wasowski that will get replaced by setuptools anyway

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updating after comment with useful info.

Based on your comment, the pip you are using is executing `/usr/bin/python` per its shebang line, so that's why setuptools is replacing your shebangs with `/usr/bin/python`.  You need to install pip using your new python, each version of python needs its own pip.

```
/usr/local/bin/python get-pip.py
```

However, you should **really** [use virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) instead.

Comment: So your saying the she-bang lines should point the the version of python I want? What if the location differs on different computers?

Comment: it doesn't matter what they point to, it could be `#!/not/a/real/python`.  As long as it's a shebang line that ends in "python", setuptools will replace it for you (during installation of the package) to point to the current python interpreter.

Comment: Doesnt work, I tried adding `/usr/bin/env python` (Also tried `/usr/local/bin/python` ) and when I install it, the script still points to `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Did you add `/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python` ?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Can you show us `pip --version` and `head -1 $(which pip)`

Comment: Might be onto something: `$ head -1 $(which pip)` is `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I installed pip after installing the new python. I installed it using `python easy_install pip` and `which python` was correct. Pip even installs all dependencies into the correct python. Why would the she-bang line still be different?

Comment: Because the pip you installed with `python easy_install pip` is not the same pip you are executing when you just run `pip`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but why would dependencies be installed into the right version of python?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63811/discussion-between-erlvolton-and-humdinger).